# Searching a substring in the entire table and paste the value of the cell that contains the substring to another datasheet

Tags: excel, vba, substring

I need to search each and every cell in the table for a substring, and copy and paste them in a single column in another worksheet. The table is comparatively big. So, I cannot give a range/column to search.

Also, I am new to Macros/VBA and below is what I wrote and tried. This did not throw any error but could not get the expected result either. Thank you in advance! :)

```
Sub FindCopyText()
Dim rCell As Range

For Each rCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
If InStr(rCell.Value, "foo") > 0 Then
rCell.Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A1").End(xlUp)(2, 1)
End If
Next rCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Provide an example of data and show an instance where the code does not work.

Comment: Can't you use AutoFilter?

Comment: Suggest you use the `Range.Find` method.

Answer (score 0):

Sir, in an effort to try an improve my own VBA , I have set about finding out how. (one of many, many ways mind you). So I wonder if this code helps you. if you hadn't found a solution yourself yet. i have used an external source to provide a basis for what I ended up doing.

It prints out cells where the substring was found in Sheet2, in Sheet4 (in a cell by addresses) and Sheet5 (by columns , and entire cells).

Also, beforehand, theres a message box but you can remove that part of the code if want. I hope this helps & is a start.

To export the matched cells from sheet2s table I toyed with the idea of an array but it was too much head aches with all the noise from the naighbours , so I opted for something else instead.

Also considered an advanced filter (which would be much faster), but again it was too much headache. im just glad i made something that works.

```
Sub FindAll13()

'PURPOSE: Find all cells containing a specified values
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim fnd As String, FirstFound As String
Dim FoundCell As Range, rng As Range
Dim myRange As Range, LastCell As Range

'What value do you want to find (must be in string form)?
  fnd = "*Happy*"

Set myRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
Set LastCell = myRange.Cells(myRange.Cells.Count)
Set FoundCell = myRange.find(What:=fnd, after:=LastCell)

'Test to see if anything was found
  If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
    FirstFound = FoundCell.Address
  Else
    GoTo NothingFound
  End If

Set rng = FoundCell

'Loop until cycled through all unique finds
  Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
    'Find next cell with fnd value
      Set FoundCell = myRange.FindNext(after:=FoundCell)

    'Add found cell to rng range variable
      Set rng = Union(rng, FoundCell)

    'Test to see if cycled through to first found cell
      If FoundCell.Address = FirstFound Then Exit Do

  Loop

'Select Cells Containing Find Value
  rng.Select
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1").Value2 = rng.Address

  MsgBox "values are" & rng.Address

  'MyArray = rng
  'Dim i
 'For i = 0 To UBound(MyArray())
 'Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(1 + i, 3).Value = rng(i)
 'Next i


    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In rng
        r.Copy
        Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("A" & lastRow + 1).Offset(0, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & lastRow + 1).Value = Range("A" & lastRow + 1).Value
    lastRow = lastRow + 1
'    Next

Next r



  'x = 0
  'For Each FoundCell In rng.Select
  'x = x + 1
  'Sheet3.Cells(1, x) = rng
  'Next




Exit Sub

'Error Handler
NothingFound:
  MsgBox "No values were found in this worksheet"

End Sub
```

All you need to do is replace the substring to find (I had "Happy" in mine, as you can see) to your substring. Remember to keep the wildcards (*) to enable substring like matches

So every cell containing your substring will be exported to sheet5 column A. & likewise prior to that the cell addresses of all & any contain matches is in cell sheet4 cell A1. (you can change it to print these anywhere you want).

let me know if this answers your question by being so kind as to tick the accepted answer box if you can. if it works for your needs (as it did for me), and/or what you might have done instead if not.